# how to find the next available input id using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tab behavior using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868707/tab-behavior-using-jquery)

Imagine that there are many text boxes in a web page and our cursor is focused on one of them randomly. Is there any solution to find out the next available textbox id using jQuery ?

Comment: What do you mean by *next available input id*? Are you cloning input elements and want to generate unique IDs? Or do you want to get the next input element in the document?

Comment: The best way is probably to tag all your elements with tabindices and then use that attribute to select the next one. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.1

Comment: You should have rephrased your original question. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to get the next input element and the elements are scattered in the DOM, you can make use of the [`.index()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method:

```
var $inputs = $('input[type="text"]');

$(document.body).on('focus', 'input[type="text"]', function() {
    var next = $inputs.eq($inputs.index(this) + 1);
});
```

If you insert input elements dynamically, you'd have to re-select the input elements and update `$inputs` accordingly.